# OpenLayers EPSG900913->EPSG4326 conversion gives wrong results

Tags: javascript, geocoding, openlayers, map-projections

I have a problem with converting pixel location from screen to degrees (EPSG4326).

The lon/lat value in EPSG900913 is correct, according to http://proj4js.org/ and google maps.

Some example values I'm getting are

```
EPSG:900913 lon: 2763836.8383036, lat: 8815158.7073107
```

after conversion

```
EPSG:4326  x: 79.18791 y: 24.08555
```

When the values should be

```
EPSG 4326: Y: 24.69090 X: 60.193680
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the relevant parts of my code.

```
$mapObj.bind("contextmenu.zoom", function (evt) {
   var _px = new OpenLayers.Pixel(evt.pageX, evt.pageY),
   _lonlat = _mapObj.getLonLatFromPixel(_px),
   _point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(_lonlat.lat, _lonlat.lon);

   _point = _point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... and the answer is, i mixed up lat & lon order on this row:

```
_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(_lonlat.lat, _lonlat.lon);
```

should be

```
_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(_lonlat.lon, _lonlat.lat);
```